# How to properly programmatically convert a XLSX file to HTML using C#?

Tags: c#, html, excel, xml

At work, we're modifying an XLSX file, and we would like to turn this modified file into an HTML file (to convert it into PDF using [Puppeteer#](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/index.html), but it's not the point here).

We know how to get XML files of this XLSX, and I already found [XSLCompiledTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=netcore-2.2) to convert XML files to HTML.

The annoyance here is that, from what I have read for XSLCompiledTransform, to transform XML file to HTML you need one stylesheet + one XML file.

This brings three problems :

- It looks like the stylesheet into XLSX for each sheet isn't well formated to use with this XSLCompiledTransform.
- The XLSX file contains multiples sheets, so we would have to fuse them in some manner, and we don't know how.
- It is not just some random XML files, they're parts of an XLSX file. Thus there are also some XML files in addition to the sheets (like a workbook and other files) and we can't figure how we could generate an HTML file which is precisely like the XLSX file as open using Excel without using these XML files.

These problems could be resumed as: We struggle to find how to generate an HTML file which will look exactly like the original whole XLSX file.

We don't really want to create an HTML file from some XML files, so any means to transform an XLSX to HTML is good.
We also know that there are some tools and libs available to directly do this, but all the ones I've found aren't free, and we would like to avoid to pay for that as it's the first time we need it and maybe the last.

**Does anyone know an accurate option to programmatically transform an XLSX file to HTML, keeping every style options and using C#?**

Comment: I am afraid to tell you that you gone end using one paid library, there is no easy out of the box solution. Some vendor offer a light weight version with limitation. If you insist to make find a free, you need to find out how many work hours you gone put on it VS if you do it. If I am wrong, I hope some body give a solution for this. The only thing I found is http://spreadsheetlight.com/

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I know that it might be hard/impossible to find something like this, but never asking for it mean never got an answer to it. BTW thank you for the lib, a quick look at it put me to think that it might not be sufficient, but I'll take a deeper try on it.

Comment: I can appreciate where you're coming from but I think the scope of this question might be too gigantic for the format of this website

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Do you think that asking how to convert an XLSX file to one unique XML file would fit better?

Comment: That's a big maybe. Generally SO questions are more low level than that and deal directly with a rather specific problem that you've run into during the process of converting that XLSX to XML, for example. There is generally an expectation that a simple [mre] along with some code can be leveraged to provide a reasonable answer. Especially the original question could be closed as off-topic for being a question about a software recommendation

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer I agree, my point was if there is a solution I would answer it. The challenge comes now if this need to be answered with code solution, than it is no longer a code solution it would be a complete project. But never give up. But maybe I am wrong on this :)